# Why do I have to group by every column in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-aurora

I had a query made on aurora sql, it was working nice, but now I need to do the same in redshift, but when I do so, it throws an error asking me to group by by every column, but obviously I don't want that.

This is the query:

```
select 
             rut,
             name,
             id,
             sum(cantidad_retornos) as cantidad_retornos,
             sum(cantidad_aceptadas) as cantidad_aceptadas,
             sum(cantidad_auto_accept) as cantidad_auto_accept,
             sum(cantidad_rechazadas) as cantidad_rechazadas,
             sum(cantidad_aceptadas) - sum(cantidad_auto_accept) as cantidad_aceptadas_manual,
             coalesce((sum(cantidad_aceptadas) - sum(cantidad_auto_accept)) / nullif(sum(cantidad_aceptadas),0)) as per_aceptadas_manual,
             coalesce(sum(cantidad_auto_accept) / nullif(sum(cantidad_aceptadas),0),0) as per_aceptadas_auto,
             coalesce(sum(cantidad_rechazadas) / nullif(sum(cantidad_retornos),0),0) AS rechazo_per,
             case
                        when coalesce(sum(cantidad_rechazadas) / nullif(sum(cantidad_retornos),0) ,0) < 0.1 or cantidad_retornos < 10 then 'Confiable' 
                        when coalesce(sum(cantidad_rechazadas) / nullif(sum(cantidad_retornos),0),0) >= 0.1 and coalesce(sum(cantidad_rechazadas) / nullif(sum(cantidad_retornos),0),0) < 0.5 then 'Estándar'
                        when coalesce(sum(cantidad_rechazadas) / nullif(sum(cantidad_retornos),0),0) >= 0.5 then 'Poco confiable'
                        else 'Sin clasificar' 
             end as nivel_confianza
         from table
         where 1=1 
         group by id, name, rut
```

I tried to group by every column, but it doesn't throw the result that I need

The error that I get:
ERROR: column "reporte_sellers_date.cantidad_retornos" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

If I group by the third column, it throws the same error but with the column number 4

Comment: Can you share the exact error?

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing the intended logic of the query.  The behavior you are seeing on Redshift is the behavior which most databases would exhibit, actually, and it is correct.

Comment: every column in the select has to be in the `GROUP BY` or have an aggregation function

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not in aurora

Comment: @nbk isn't sum and aggregation function? If I group by every column then the result is wrong

Comment: your case has `or cantidad_retornos`

Answer (score 2):

In the first option in the CASE statement you have `or cantidad_retornos` without any aggregating function such as SUM().  This is why Redshift is saying it needs to be in a `group by`. You also alias this name to the sum of the column of the same name. So the is a choice the database needs to make about which one to use - the source column or the aggregate. It looks like Aurora is choosing the aggregate but Redshift is choosing the source column.

Using the same name for an aggregate as a source column is not a good idea as you are relying on the query compiler to make a choice for you. This means the query can break when the compiler is updated or if you port the query to a different database.

To fix this you can either add the SUM() aggregation to the use of `cantidad_retornos` in the CASE statement or use the aggregate from above in the query but give it a unique name.